# How to delete all local and remote Git on Xcode 7 project

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I'm working on an iOS Xcode project whose previous developer has configured and committed to local git and remote git using his account. Now I want to delete every source control existing on the project (local and remote) and recreate a new one. How can I make everything fresh so that I can commit and use the source control? (I don't have the previous developer account.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in order to delete your local git you need  to open your file system where your project is located and delete the **.git** folder. please notice that this folder is hidden by default so you will need to show hidden files and folders before doing it.

Delete of remote repository should be done on the server. If for example your are using github.com then you need to go to github.com and inside your repository go to **settings** tab and on the bottom you will see the **Danger Zone** there you can delete  your remote repository.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already make command to show .git file. But there is another gitnore. Do we need to delete it also?

Comment: No you don't gitignore contains all the files and folders that will be ignored when you sync your local git repo with your remote repo. You can leave this file there because it's also great for future use when you will decide the use git again for this project.

Comment: So just delete the .git file is enough?

Comment: it's not a file.. it's a folder... just delete it and that's it.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to remove the invisible `.git` directory at the root level of the project. From there, you can recreate the repository and any remotes.

**Be warned**, this will delete all history for this project!

Comment: You can easily do this by copying all the (visible) files in the project folder to a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all local and origin branch from XCode 8 follow these steps :
1. Source Controll / ProjectName/ Configure ProjectName.
2.  In Configure ProjectName Window select Branches tab.
3. Select any branch name from local or origin.
4. Click on "-" icon on bottom left.

That branch will be removed from local machine.

And for removing branches from Github server you can delete repos from server.